# Castle Falkenstein: Is there a faster Magic system?

Tags: house-rules, magic, diceless

I love running games in the **Castle Falkenstein** diceless system.  However, I find the CF magic system to be a little slow (to set up, run and play) for a high-fantasy campaign.

Can anyone suggest alternatives, or suggest links to alternate systems that preserve the card-diceless feel, but speed up the play?

Comment: The CF tag is no problem; "publisher tags" aren't the practice on rpg.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

There is a faster magic system for playing Castle Falkenstein... unfortunately, it's the GURPS Castle Falkenstein rules, having also the side effect of GURPS  rules for everything else.

On the other hand, one could simply decide that each spell simply required a sorcery roll to trigger, instead of the mana gathering system; if doing so, it's a small step further to use the alternate dice-based mechanics from Comme Il Faut. In fact, using the dice mechanics might be a viable option anyway, simply replacing the mana total with a number of dice rolls totalling the needed mana.

Still, slow gathering of mana is part of the CF magic mechanics - change it at your own risk as far as feel of the game and setting. Without otherwise changing anything else, just using a single mana card flip as a rate might be a workable, if drastic, solution to mechanical slowness.

Comment: Interesting idea.  However I don't want to change the core game mechanic by going to GURPs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the Comme Il Faut sourcebook? It has alternate rules and such, not sure if any of them would be "faster" or even apply to the magic system as I never picked it up myself. It's available on [DTRPG](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/25120/Comme-Il-Faut?it=1&filters=0_0_10133_0_0&manufacturers_id=13) and has good reviews.

Comment: I do have Comme Il Faut and I was looking for something a little more flashy and dramatic.  Something that gets up there with the SpellGuns of Six-guns and Sorcery.

Comment: @SteveED I took the liberty of examining *The Book of Sigils*, too. No new mechanics in there; just new Lore.

Comment: @Jadasc - thank you, i also have the Book of Sigils and the Journal of Oberon, and neither really have what I want